# Is it more secure to have a kubernetes pod with a read-only file-system, but with some read-write exceptions?

Tags: security, kubernetes

In kubernetes you can set "readOnlyRootFilesystem: true" for a container, in order to make the container's file system read-only, thus making it more secure.

However, in my particular case, my application still needs to write some files, so I need to add some read-write volume mounts for some particular paths.

Now my question is: if I introduce these writable locations into my setup, does it really make a difference from a security point of view if the rest of the file system is read-only?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend adding more details about your specific situation to keep this from being a more opinion-based question. Are there particular security concerns relevant to you? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for excellent advice on writing questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, having the main filesystem in the container as read-only with specific locations (for example logging or temporary files) as read-write will, in general, improve the overall security of your container.

An attacker trying to compromise your contained application from the outside, likely won't know which directories are read-write, so would have difficulty in placing their payloads onto disk.

It's not a perfect defence, by any manner of means, however it's a good layer of security, and if you know which directories need to be read-write, a relatively simple step to implement.